# ClassCastException when inflating Android fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

First of all, my code was working perfectly and started this weird issue by itself. I've got a Fragment that contains a `TextView` *yes, a regular text view, I can verify this by examining my layout file*:

[image]

In my code (which I haven't touched *neither in layout XML nor Java class file*), I am casting it to `TextView`:

`TextView nameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.postHeaderNameView);`

This was working normally, until suddenly I started to get this error:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`.

Why on Earth Android is thinking that my TextView is a rounded image view? Yes, I *do* have rounded image views, but none of them are called `postHeaderNameView`. Cleaning and rebuilding the project did nothing.

What am I doing wrong, and why a working project suddenly started to err on this?

Comment: Try to `Clean -> Rebuild` your project.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for code that you can copy into you posts. One thing that could be causing this is somewhere you have a `@+id/postHeaderNameView` that **is** a `RoundedImageView`

Comment: you are try to convert imageview to textview... that is Exception.... and aslo post logcat....

Comment: @jaydroider I already did that as I've said.

Comment: @ExceptionLover or really? I know what the error means, I am trying to understand why this is the case where my view is not a rounded image view

Comment: Post your `XML` code and Full `Stack Trace`.

Comment: i think you are use RoundedImageView another activity or fragment.. post your xml layout.....

Comment: May be you are inflating another layout  in the fragment other than the layout you took screencap of

Comment: Please post the relevant xml code along with the log details for the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It went away after a rebuild/restart as always. I think I should get used to restarting whenever weird problem occurs when working with Android.